# in CasperJS, how do you wait for JSON to complete loading?

Tags: javascript, json, casperjs

I am visiting a site that emits a (large) JSON response.  A click triggers the request:

```
casper.then(function li10() {
    casper.click(SEARCH_BUTTON_CSS);
});
```

But according to my web proxy, the client closes the connection before receiving the entire response.  I've tried waiting for the URL to appear.  It waits for the URL as expected, but that doesn't appear to be sufficient:

```
casper.then(function li11() {
    casper.waitForUrl(/\/search-results\/p\?/,
                      function() { 
                          var search_url = casper.getCurrentUrl();
                          console.log('found search results, url = ' + search_url);
                      },
                      function() { 
                          console.log('failed to find search results');
                          casper.exit();
                      },
                      10000);
});
```

So: what is something dependable that I can wait for that will guarantee that the JSON code has completely loaded before proceeding to the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you would fill a search field, click a button and the JavaScript makes an Ajax request to receive a JSON response to then parse it and display the results.

`casper.waitForUrl()` is used to wait for the page URL to change to the specified one. It has nothing to do with resources that are loaded separately such as AJAX responses.

You either need to

- find out the specific URL that is requested for the search action and use `casper.waitForResource()` to wait for that specific resource or
- devise a specific selector that appears when the search data is parsed and injected into the page with `casper.waitForSelector()`.

Comment: By dawn's early light, I realize you're right: I need to replicate the URL generated by the click, but I actually need to capture the JSON before it gets incorporated to the DOM, so what I really need is to make a call to `casper#download()`.

Comment: You've given a good answer to a bad question, so I'll give you the check.  Rather than edit my original question into something else, I'll post a new question.  Keep an eye out for it!  :)